# aggregate function in mongoose node.js returning no record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have seen few questions related to this .  But unable to find answer that can help me.

Here is my server side node.js code using mongoose. This code is just printing "Success in fetching data[]" in the console.

```
var kmphDBSchema = commonRouter.kmphDBSchema;
    var locationSchema = new kmphDBSchema({result:{locations:{id:String,parent_id:String,countryCode:String,name:String}}});
    var locationModel = commonRouter.kmphMongoClient.model('mgh_locations',locationSchema);

exports.getLocations =  function(request, response) { 
    var locationName = '/.*' + request.params.locationName + '.*/';
    console.log("locationName: " + locationName);

    locationModel.aggregate(
        [
           { $unwind:"$locations"}
          ,{ $project:{_id:0,locations:1} }
          ,{ $match:{"locations.name": locationName}}
       ]
      , function (err, res) {
        console.log('Error=' + err); 
          if (err){
            console.log('Error in fetching locations' + err);
            return (err);
          }
          console.log('Success in fetching data' + JSON.stringify(res)); 
          response.send(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
}
```

Here is data returned by query in mongo shell. **This data is NOT returned when data is fetched from node.js using mongoose.**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "locations" : {
                "id" : "1",
                "parent_id" : "531",
                "countryCode" : "IN",
                "name" : "Noida"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "locations" : {
                "id" : "407",
                "parent_id" : "531",
                "countryCode" : "IN",
                "name" : "Greater Noida"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}.
```

And here is the original JSON document

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548b15d700dcf350ea6a9e1e"),
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "parent_id" : "531",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Noida"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "parent_id" : "531",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "New Delhi"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "parent_id" : "531",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Gurgaon"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "11",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Agra"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "12",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Jaipur"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "13",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Hyderabad"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "14",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Lucknow"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "15",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Kanpur"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "16",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Lansdowne"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "18",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Bangalore"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "19",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Nainital"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "20",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Bhimtal"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "21",
            "parent_id" : "0",
            "countryCode" : "IN",
            "name" : "Kolkata"
        }
]
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. The "title" says "nothing returned" but you show a result. So no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Data is not getting printed. In console, log statement is just printing "Success in fetching data[]". The exact data is not getting printed. Updated Question for more clarification

Comment: New account. Please edit your question with details rather than attempt to add more in comments. Just Comment and "tag" people you want to alert to your edits. You seem to be asking that your aggregation gives different results in mongoose to the shell. I don't feel that you are truly posting all relevant code since what you have posted should work the same.

Comment: I have updated the question again.

Comment: I suspect the "pluralization" code of mongoose to be the real culprit here. Mongoose model takes "three" arguments. Try: `mongoose.model('mgh_locations',locationSchema,'mgh_locations')`. That probably gets the correct collection when specified.

Comment: Above solution doesnt work Neil

Comment: That's okay.A longer response was warranted and given.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for more clarification for others when this is a search term that matches.

As an ODM or ( Object Document Mapper ) interface, the Mongoose library has some certain aspects in it's  functions that might confuse the unwary. The most common aspect is clearly the "naming" of models. Mongoose follows a pattern that uses a model name as a representation of an  "Object" in the "pluralized" form when "naming" the collection by default. This leads to some problems.

The library used here leads to some common inflections. Therefore with the following example:

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
     Schema = mongoose.Schema;


 var personSchema = new Schema({
     "name": String,
     "tile": STring
 });

 mongoose.model( "Person", personShema );
```

Expects that the "model" in the collection storage should be called `people`. This is standard `EN` or english language inflection bestowed by the library used. But there is a "default" handling of this that is present in the base method employed by the mongoose library itself. As the function actually accepts "three" arguments, with the "third" being an explicit match to the collection name rather than default "pluralization".

```
mongoose.model( "Person", personSchema, "Person" );
```

Now that `collection` is actually named `Person` rather than `People` and is therefore more like what you might expect.

Fair3 note is given that the "default" actions are exactly what is expected from **good** programming practice. The "Model" here is a "singular" class representation, and the "collection" underlying represents "many" of these "objects" in a collection as is basically implied. So it is the right thing to really do.

If you are applying a "model" to a structure that already has defined it's "collection" names, then use the "third" argument to specify that name when instantiating the object.This makes it clear for the engine and also for reading your code.